# Fill Identity Of WinForms Into Textboxes

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms

I have Three Forms as below:

Form1

Form2

Form3

The Form1 and Form3 are communicating with Form2. I want If Form1 visited to Form2 than

Form1 Should leave it’s identity to **Form2’s textbox1**.  If Form3 visited to Form2 than Form3

should leave it’s Identity to **Form2’s textbox2.**

Is it possible?.

Here is Visted Means as below.

**By Form1**

```
Form2 f2= new Form2();
f2.Show();
```

**By Form3**

```
Form2 f2= new Form2();
f2.Show();
```

And Identity Like **"Form1"** and **"Form3"**

Comment: Can you show the code that does the communication between Form1 and Form2?

Comment: What exactly do you understand by "visited"?

Comment: What is "visited" and "identity"?

Comment: @Liviu Visited means if form2.Show() by Form1 than Form1 should leave it's Identity To Form2's Textbox1. same way if Form3 visited than it should leave it's identity to Form2's Textbox. Itdentity should be like "Form1" and "Form3" on Textboxes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The best thing to do is overload the `Show` method for each of your forms to accept something like a "previous form" parameter that will serve as a reference to the caller** (you could do this either as a `Form` object, whose properties you could then access, or simply as a `String`). Then, wherever you show a second form from an existing form, you pass information about the existing form into the `Show` method for the second form. The second form's `Show` method would take care of updating its textbox with the name of the form that displayed it.

For example, each form would contain an overloaded `Show` method:

```
public void Show(Form previousForm)
{
    //Set the textbox on this form to contain the name of the calling form
    myTextBox.Text = previousForm.Name;

    //Call the base class's method to show this form
    base.Show();
}
```

And you would show one form from another by calling its overloaded `Show` method:

```
private void ShowOtherFormButton(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Create a new instance of the form you want to display
    Form2 myOtherForm = new Form2();

    //Show the other form, passing the calling form as a parameter
    myOtherForm.Show(this);
}
```

This way, no form is responsible for or even allowed to update controls contained by another form. You don't have to expose any additional properties or remember to call any additional methods on the forms you want to show—it's built right into the `Show` method that you have to call anyway.

Alternatively, you could overload each form's constructor in the same way, but that won't work if you want to be able to move between existing instances of each form. You'll only be able to specify information about the previous form when you're creating a *new* instance of each form.

Comment: Your are right. but I think your VS-version is deferent than mine. I have to create an object of class I mean create instance of forms in my version. like "Form1 f1= new Form1(); f1.Show(this)

Comment: ... You have suggested "Form2.Show(this); is working for you?.

Comment: I was assuming that the forms had already been created. If you have not yet created the form, you will need to do so before calling the `Show` method as you normally do. Thanks for the comment; I edited my answer.

Answer (score 2):

I believe you are asking for the form that opens Form2 to set some specific value to the textbox. You could have a property on Form2 that sets the textbox text.

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
     /*.......*/
       public string Identity
       {
           set
           {
              textbox1.Text = value;
           }
       }
}
```

Then in Form1 or Form3:

```
Form2 form2 = new Form2();
form2.Identity = this.Name;
form2.Show();
```

Comment: Your code is fine but there is little mistake which you have to edited like: " Form2 f2 = new Form2();
            f2.Identity = this.Name;
            f2.Show();"

Comment: ... you have miss to create object of class so rectify it.

Comment: ... or may be you are using deferent version of VS than me.

Answer (score 0):

You will need a reference to the caller. You can do this by overriding the constructor of the Form.

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    Form _caller;//Caller form

    //Default constructor 
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public Form1(Form caller)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this._caller = caller;
        textbox2.Text = caller.Name;
    }   
}
```

All you have to do now is call Form2 using the new constructor:

```
Form2 form2Instance = new Form2(this);
form2Instance.Show();
```

Whichever form will call Form2, will now have it's name written on textbox2 of Form2

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass data between the window forms(ie.,the name of the form in this scenario)so that you can get it in Form2.
Refer the lint to pass data between window forms: http://www.vbdotnetheaven.com/UploadFile/thiagu304/passdata12262006073406AM/passdata.aspx